# MUI row vs column Grid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';

const Item = styled(Paper)(({ theme }) => ({
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? '#1A2027' : '#fff',
  ...theme.typography.body2,
  padding: theme.spacing(1),
  textAlign: 'center',
  color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
}));

export default function BasicGrid() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ width:'80vw',height:'80vh',background:'lightblue' }}>
      <Grid container spacing={2} direction='row'>
        <Grid item xs={8}>
          <Item>xs=8</Item>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <Item>xs=4</Item>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

In MUI,When `direction='row'` we have the following output

[image]

And when `direction='column'`

[image]

If we think like `flexbox` in `css`, we expect the following

[image]

My question is, What is the purpose of `xs={number}` in `column` mode? And how can I have the expected output with `Grid`?

Answer (score 0):

if you give `direction="column"` to `container` grid and `xs={number}` in grid `item`, then maximum size of column is size of `xs` props.

```
<Box>
      <Grid 
        container
        direction="column"
        justifyContent="center"
        alignItems="center"
      >
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Item>xs=12</Item>
        </Grid>
       <Grid xs={10}>
          <Item>xs=10</Item>
        </Grid>
        <Grid xs={2}>
          <Item>xs=2</Item>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Box>
```